# Find unique dataset with max. value from 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Imaging following table

- ID:PrimaryKey (Sequence generated Number)
- ColA:ForeignKey(Number)
- ColB:ForeignKey(Number)
- ColC:ForeignKey(Number)
- State:Enumeration(Number) 10,20,30,... 90
- ValidFrom:TimeStamp(6)
- LastUpdate:(6)

I know created a query to fetch any combination in the highest states (70 and above) The combination ColA,ColB and ColC should be unqiue. If there is a validfrom available the highest would win. If there are 2 in state 90 the newest would win:

So for some table like this

```
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| ColA | ColB | ColC | State |ValidFrom    |LastUpdate  |
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 10    |  null       | 10.10.2018 | //Excluded
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 70    |  null       | 09.10.2018 | // lower State
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 90    |  null       | 05.05.2018 | // older LastUpdate
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 90    |  null       | 12.07.2018 | //Should Win
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 2    | 1    | 90    |  18.10.2018 | 12.07.2018 | //Should Win
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1    | 2    | 1    | 90    |  null       | 18.11.2018 | //loose against ValidFrom
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 3    | 2    | 1    | 90    |  02.12.2018 | 04.08.2018 | //lower ValidFrom
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 3    | 2    | 1    | 70    |  19.10.2018 | 17.11.2018 | //lower state
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 3    | 2    | 1    | 90    |  18.10.2018 | 14.08.2018 | //Should win
|------|------|------|-------|-------------|------------|
```

So as you can see the combination of ColA,ColB and ColC should be unqiue at the end.

So I started writing a script gives me all the data with the highest states per combination:

```
   SELECT MAINSELECT.*
FROM
   FOO MAINSELECT
WHERE 
   MAINSELECT.STATE >= 70
AND NOT EXISTS
   (    SELECT SUBSELECT.ID
    FROM 
        FOO SUBSELECT
    WHERE SUBSELECT.ID <> MAINSELECT.ID
       AND SUBSELECT.COLA = MAINSELECT.COLA
       AND SUBSELECT.COLB = MAINSELECT.COLB
       AND SUBSELECT.COLC = MAINSELECT.COLC
       AND SUBSELECT.STATE > MAINSELECT.STATE);
```

This now gives me all in the highest state. As I do not want to use an OR statement I tried to solve the problem to query either NULL as Validfrom or the MAX in 2 different queries (and use union). So I tried to extend this base SELECT like this to get all with a ValidFrom != null && Max(ValidFrom):

```
SELECT MAINSELECT.*
FROM
   FOO MAINSELECT
WHERE 
   MAINSELECT.STATE >= 70
   MAINSELECT.VALIDFROM IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
   (    SELECT SUBSELECT.ID
    FROM 
        FOO SUBSELECT
    WHERE SUBSELECT.ID <> MAINSELECT.ID
       AND SUBSELECT.COLA = MAINSELECT.COLA
       AND SUBSELECT.COLB = MAINSELECT.COLB
       AND SUBSELECT.COLC = MAINSELECT.COLC
       AND SUBSELECT.STATE > MAINSELECT.STATE)
AND NOT EXISTS
   (    SELECT SUBSELECT.ID
    FROM 
        FOO SUBSELECT
    WHERE SUBSELECT.ID <> MAINSELECT.ID -- Should not be the same
       AND SUBSELECT.COLA = MAINSELECT.COLA -- Same combination!
       AND SUBSELECT.COLB = MAINSELECT.COLB
       AND SUBSELECT.COLC = MAINSELECT.COLC
       AND SUBSELECT.STATE = MAINSELECT.STATE --Filter on same state!
       AND SUBSELECT.VALIDFROM > MAINSELECT.VALIDFROM);
```

But this doesn't seem to work because now nothing ist printed.

I am expecting just row: 5 and 9! [Starting at 1 ;-)]

And I currently get row: 5, 7 and 9!

So the combination [3,2,1] is duplicate.

I do not get why the 2nd NOT EXISTS does not work. It's like there are 0F*** given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of using NOT EXISTS I am trying to use the max, rpad and coalesce to create a string which I compare:

```
SELECT 
    MAINSELECT.*
FROM 
    FOO MAINSELECT
WHERE (1 = 1)
    AND MAINSELECT.STATE >= 70
    AND coalesce(to_char(MAINSELECT.state), rpad('0', 3, '0') ) || coalesce(to_char(MAINSELECT.validfrom,'YYMMDDhh24missFF'), rpad('0', 18, '0') ) || coalesce(to_char(MAINSELECT.lastupdate,'YYMMDDhh24missFF'), rpad('0', 18, '0') )
    = (select max(coalesce(to_char(SUBSELECT.state), rpad('0', 3, '0') ) || coalesce(to_char(SUBSELECT.validfrom,'YYMMDDhh24missFF'), rpad('0', 18, '0') )|| coalesce(to_char(SUBSELECT.lastupdate,'YYMMDDhh24missFF'), rpad('0', 18, '0')))                
        FROM 
            FOO SUBSELECT
        WHERE (1 = 1)
            AND SUBSELECT.STATE >= 70
            AND SUBSELECT.COLA = MAINSELECT.COLA
            AND SUBSELECT.COLB = MAINSELECT.COLB
            AND SUBSELECT.COLC = MAINSELECT.COLC
  );
```

This creates a simple string with the values from the columns STATE,VALIDFROM and LASTUPDATE and is then trying to find the max of these! stating with the State which has the highest number and comes in the front!

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd9f70e4c016bc0e74a0be8bb0a08bac)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (
    select row_number() over (
                        partition by cola, colb, colc 
                        order by state desc, validfrom desc nulls last, lastupdate desc) rn, 
           foo.*
      from foo)
  where rn = 1
```

`7` wins against `9` because `2018-12-02` is newer than `2018-10-18`.

Explanation:

- `partition by cola, colb, colc` causes that for each combination of these columns numbering is done separately,
- next are criteria of ordering, so higher `state` wins, then newer, not nullable `validfrom` wins, and at the end newer `lastupdate` wins.

For each combinantion of `a, b, c` we get separate set of numbered rows. Outer query filters only rows numbered as `1`.

Comment: In fact your approach is simple and would work. Except by the problem that the TEMP Tablespace cannot be further enlarged by Oracle :-) ORA-01652. This occurs because the database has to much data and the select statement is not really optimized for this.

Comment: It's technical problem. This query hits table only once, does not contain any `exists` subqueries, it's hard to make it simplier. Analytical functions like `rank`, `dense_rank`, `row_number` are designed to be used in rankings (among others) as you can see in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0201).